# Существует ли микроразметка для поиска по сайту? И стоит ли вообще её внедрять?

Tags: seo, оптимизация-сайтов, микроразметка

[image: Пример поиска на сайте]

Есть ли в принципе микроразметка для поиска по сайту? Я нашёл лишь такую документацию по этому вопросу - https://developers.google.com/search/docs/data-types/sitelinks-searchbox?hl=ru

И судя по этому пояснению, то достаточно внести в микроразметку name инпута, в которое будет вноситься информация?

Answer (score 0):

В руководстве Гугл, ссылку на которое вы указали, есть следующая информация:

> Когда ваш сайт появляется в результатах Google Поиска, под ссылкой на
>   него может быть показано ещё одно окно поиска, которое будет
>   относиться только к самому сайту. По умолчанию поиск в окне
>   выполняется с помощью технологии Google, но вы можете применить в нем
>   собственную поисковую систему или настроить показ результатов в
>   связанном мобильном приложении. Для этого вам нужно добавить
>   структурированные данные в код своего сайта.

В этой информации есть фраза "По умолчанию поиск в окне выполняется с помощью технологии Google", которая, по моему скромному мнению, означает наличие на веб-сайте **[системы пользовательского поиска (CSE)](https://developers.google.com/custom-search/docs/tutorial/introduction)** Гугл.

> И стоит ли вообще её внедрять?

Это может быть полезным для веб-сайтов, которые являются вертикальными поисковыми системами, например, поисковая система автомобильных запасных частей какого то автомобильного дилера или авторемонтной мастерской. Коротко говоря, это может быть полезным для веб-сайта представляющего множество объектов или сущностей. Однако, здесь важно создание правильных и релевантных структурированных данных и создание структурированной иерархии поисковой системы веб-сайта, включая файлы сериализации для **[Датасет](https://www.w3.org/TR/vocab-dcat-2/)**. Разумеется, можно упрощать поисковую систему, однако это не всегда лучшее решение.